# How to remove multiple elements from a list of lists?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dlib

I have list of list elements. In my case, I am using dlib tracker. Appending all detected tracker to a list. I am trying to remove some of the tracker from the list. To make it simple, I have a list like below,

```
[[1, 2, 3], [4,5,6], [7, 8,9], [2,54,23], [4,12,5], [3,2,6]]
```

I want to remove list item whenever I found 4 in the list.

For that I used below snippet to find the index to remove elements.

```
t=  [[1, 2, 3], [4,5,6], [7, 8,9], [2,54,23], [4,12,5], [3,2,6]]
del_item = []
idx = 0
for item in t:
    if 4 in item:
        del_item.append(idx)
    idx+=1
print(del_item)
```

So far good. I have index of elements to be deleted. I am stuck at how to delete multiple indexes in list of list?

Expected output:

```
[[1, 2, 3], [7, 8,9], [2,54,23], [3,2,6]]
```

Comment: `[sub_l for sub_l in t if 4 not in sub_l]`

Comment: `[i for i in t if 4 not in i]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it simply with one line using list comprehension:

```
trackers = [[1, 2, 3], [4,5,6], [7, 8,9], [2,54,23], [4,12,5], [3,2,6]]
filtered = [x for x in trackers if 4 not in x]
print(filtered)
```

Output:

```
[[1, 2, 3], [7, 8,9], [2,54,23], [3,2,6]]
```

Answer (score 1):

This task might be done using list comprehension (as already shown) or using `filter`:

```
t = [[1, 2, 3], [4,5,6], [7, 8,9], [2,54,23], [4,12,5], [3,2,6]]
tclean = list(filter(lambda x:4 not in x, t))
print(tclean)  # [[1, 2, 3], [7, 8, 9], [2, 54, 23], [3, 2, 6]]
```

To use `filter` you need function - in this case I used lambda to make nameless function, though normal function might be used too. `filter` return iterable so I used `list` on it to get list.